# From my http GET JSON request to CouchDB I want to get the nested keys and values out and remove total rows and id

Tags: get, couchdb

My GET JSON brings back from COUChDB
{"total_rows":6,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"51585142d8f2851d34c9b7dc8c003997","key":"itemName","value":{"nestedkey1":"nestedvalue1","nestedkey2":"nestedvalue2","nestedkey3":"nestedvalue2","nestedkey4":"nestedvalue4","nestedkey5"}},

I want to remove  {"total_rows":6,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"51585142d8f2851d34c9b7dc8c003997","key":"itemName"

So I am left with the wrapper/parent "value" that has the nested keys and nested values I really want and so it is presented in the following JSON format {"nestedkey1":"nestedvalue1","nestedkey2":"nestedvalue2","nestedkey3":"nestedvalue2","nestedkey4":"nestedvalue4","nestedkey5"}}, as my json

I've tried CouchB mapping/views and jquery client side function/result filtering but I'm new to this and could use some insight into achieving my objective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using jQuery on the client side. You could do this in the success callback of `get()`

```
var value = [];
$.get( "url/to/view", function( data ) {
  $.each(data.rows, function(index, row){
    value.push(row.value);
  });
});
```

That way, you have the rows in `data`.

Comment: hi thanks for your timely the response
I've implemented your suggestion I'm not getting in the browser developer tools

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

{"total_rows":6,"offset":0,"rows":[

Here's my revised script

function getJSONData() {
var value = [];
var couchDB ="http://X.X.X.X:5984/databasename/_design/name/_view/All%20Content?jsoncallback=?";
    $.getJSON( couchDB , function( data )  {
        format: "jsonp"
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.rows, function(index, row){
        value.push(row.value);
         });
    });
}

Comment: Make sure your syntax is correct. You need `;` between `format: "jsonp"` and `console.log(data)`.